# Changing Locale of a printstream in Java

Tags: java, locale, printstream

I'm working on a project in which you can draw lines on a canvas and save it in a textfile with coordinates for each line.

However, when I try to save it with [this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yxre.png), and write it to the textfile, all [dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yxre.png) are replaced by [commas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32CU4.png).

I assume this is due to my language on the PC being European, so I've tried to find a workaround by setting the Locale of the `printstream` to `Locale.US`, but without luck.

How can I possibly fix this without changing the language of my entire PC?

Comment: Please copy/paste the code itself rather than pasting links to images of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The images you've linked to (which, as has been mentioned would be better as copied and pasted into the question) all show the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I fixed this by changing the Locale in my 'main' method:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Comment: Or better, Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); :)